# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users.urls'

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.conf.urls import include, url

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^users/', include(('users.urls', 'users'), namespace = 'users')),
        url(r'', include(('learning_logs.urls', 'learning_logs'), namespace = 'learning_logs')),

    ]
```

When I run the server It gives the above error

Comment: can you share the filetree, the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting, and the `urls.py` of your `user` app?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding “users.apps.UsersConfig” in settings.py under INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add urls.py file in each module.